# How to handle back-stack in Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

case 1: I have 3 fragments A,B,C. When I am moving from A->B->C and then by pressing a save button on C fragment , I come back to fragment B and now when I press the back button at this point (in fragment B), it takes me to fragment C (C fragment is stored in the backstack) but I need to take the user to fragment A instead of C.

---> I am using this below code when user presses on back button of fragment B.

```
navController!!.popBackStack()
```

case 2: When I am moving A->B and now if I press back button it takes me back to fragment A. (This is working fine) . But in above case (case 1), it takes the user to fragment C instead of A.

How should I handle this backstack case?

Comment: add some code so we can know where exactly issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call same code

```
navController!!.popBackStack()
```

after saving button click and before redirection to B fragment

so in C Fragment code will be

```
//save button clicked 
// you logic and code 
navController!!.popBackStack()
//navigate back to B fragment 

navController!!.navigate(B fragment ID)
```

Comment: can you explain how it worked??

Comment: navController!!.popBackStack() 
it will clear current fragment from back stack the redirect to your destination